# Jquery get href value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to get value from a href button. Here I have just developed a code which show all href value. Actually I need to get value from where I click.

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.me").click(function(){
    var number = $('a').text();

    alert(number);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can use $(this) to reference the element that was clicked (or otherwise used)

Like so:

```
$("a.me").click(function(){
    var number = $(this).text();
    alert(number);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.me").click(function(){
    //It's not clear if you want the href attribute or the text() of the <a>
    //this gives you the href. if you need the text $(this).text();
    var number = this.href;
    alert(number);

  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a.me").click(function(){
    var number = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(number);
});
```

Comment: This answer works best if you need just the anchor. i.e. #anchor instead of website.com/page.html#anchor or the value of the text clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = $(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: No need to use `$(this).attr('href')`, you are making two extra jQuery calls

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.me").click(function(){
      var target=$(this).attr("href");
      alert(target);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the answers above will work or you could use

```
...
$("a.me").click(function(e){
    var number = $(e.target).text();
    alert(number);
});
```